# What is the format of iTunes Artwork file?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I am about to complete my mobile application, now i have to create iTunes Artwork file.
I could not see any extension of the file in a sample i downloaded for reference.

How do i export my Vector image into iTunes Artwork file?

Comment: Good question. Apple fails to document the file format: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a PNG image without the .png extension.

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: i tried to remove .png extension from my artwork file.. and when i deployed, the artwork icon is not showing up in iTunes (when testing)

Comment: Can your reference any Apple documentation on this?

Comment: @BasilBourque Reference link added.